# Urlencode/decode, different representation of the same string

Tags: node.js, hash, urlencode

I am a bit out of my comfort zone here, so I'm not even sure I'm aproaching the problem appropriately. Anyhow, here goes:

So I have a problem where I shall hash some info with sha1 that will work as that info's id.
when a client wants to signal what current info is being used, it sends a percent-encoded sha1-string.

So one example is, my server hashes some info and gets a hex representation like so:
`44 c1 b1 0d 6a de ce 01 09 fd 27 bc 81 7f 0e 90 e3 b7 93 08`

and the client sends me

`D%c1%b1%0dj%de%ce%01%09%fd%27%bc%81%7f%0e%90%e3%b7%93%08`

Removing the % we get

`D c1 b1 0dj de ce 01 09 fd 27 bc 81 7f 0e 90 e3 b7 93 08`

which matches my hash except for the beginning D and the j after the 0d, but replacing those with their ascii hex no, we have identical hash.

So, as I have read and understood the urlencoding, the standard would allow a client to send the D as either D or %44? So different clients would be able to send different representations off the same hash, and I will not be able to just compare them for equality?

I would prefer to be able to compare the urlencoded strings as they are when they are sent, but one way to do it would be to decode them, removing all '%' and get the ascii hex value for whatever mismatch I get, much like the D and the j in my above example.

This all seems to be a very annoying way to do things, am I missing something, please tell me I am? :)

I am doing this in node.js but I suppose the solution would be language/platform agnostic.

Comment: Why is the client sending the sha1 hash like that instead of the literal "44c1b10d6adece0109fd27bc817f0e90e3b79308"? Are you in control of what the client sends?

Comment: Not in control of the client, and there are multiple clients that, to the best of my knowledge, can send different representation of the same hash. The clients in question are torrent clients if that would matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this crude solution for now:

```
var unreserved = 'A B C D E F G H I J S O N K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Za b c d e f g h i j s o n k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z + 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - _ . ~';

function hexToPercent(hex){
var index = 0,
end = hex.length,
delimiter = '%',
step = 2,
result = '',
tmp = '';

if(end % step !== 0){
    console.log('\'' + hex + '\' must be dividable by ' + step + '.');
    return result;
}

while(index < end){
    tmp = hex.slice(index, index + step);

    if(unreserved.indexOf(String.fromCharCode('0x' + tmp)) !== -1){
        result = result + String.fromCharCode('0x' + tmp);
    }
    else{
        result = result + delimiter + tmp;
    }
    index = index + step;

}
return result;

}
```